# What is the My Site search experience in geographically distributed model?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, my-site

I'm developing an architecture model for my company's global SharePoint footprint and have a question on the people search experience for a geographically distributed model. My plan right now is to have a local farm in each region (Americas, EMEA, and Asia) including a My Site web app set up as the trusted location for each region. My plan for search on "regular" content was to set up a federated search to the other 2 farms for each region, but I don't know how that works with People Search results.

Do I need to crawl the My Site applications for the other 2 farms from each region to have people's profiles show up in People Search? Are the profiles distinct enough from My Sites that if I do a full profile synchronization on each farm that will feed the people search results? Would people search results show up as part of the federated search?

Thanks for any help. I don't have the environment up yet to properly test this to determine the answers myself.

Comment: Is there a strong reason why you want local farms for each location. Unless you are targeting a large user base this can be an overkill.

Comment: Agree with Karthik to have a geographically distributed model is big Hassal. I prefer to paln properly of distributed Farm.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Federated Search, you can specify a scope in addition to keywords:

http:///_layouts/srchrss.aspx?k={keywords}&s={scope}

Since People search is already a scope in SharePoint, you can setup a federated search source for remote people results.

Be aware however, to security trim federated search results you must have Kerberos configured between your farms, otherwise search is either anonymous, or uses a delegated credential and you will get no security trimming. The second concern with federated is that you don't get unified search results. The people results from your remote farms will not be mixed with your local farm results so you are going to have to consider how to setup the search center user experience for how you display all these different federated source results.